# Kibana gets 404 on any dashboard

Tags: kibana

In testing elk I get a blank screen from Kibana and the console shows this

http://kibana.mydomain.com/app/dashboards/default.json?1422999410885 404 (Not found)

- All 3 parts of elk are on one machine
- I have elastic search running and I created an index with a couple of documents
- Sense is working perfectly
- I've tried several variations of the elasticsearch param in config.js

elasticsearch: "httpx://"+window.location.hostname+":9200"

elasticsearch: "httpx://myIpAddress:9200"

elasticsearch: "httpx://myfullyqualifiedmachinename:9200"

(i put httpx there because stackoverflow says I don't have the rep to post links)

I think that the fact that I can see the kibana tool bar at the top indicates the site is working but it just cannot find the json dashboards.

- version kibana-3.1.2
- version logstash-1.4.2
- version elasticsearch-1.4.2

and tried elasticsearch-1.3.0 as I've read about issues between 1.4 and kibana.

- my machine is windows 7
- I've added to elasticsearch.yml

http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"

http.cors.enabled: true

Thanks for any helps or tips.

Comment: Can you check the kibana.yml file and the port mentioned in the file along with URL to verify you are entering the same url with port. Can you please post an image or some way to  know what exactly is the problem you are facing? The above mentioned link is unavailable to view.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I no longer use the elk stack.